# Prestashop module remote API request

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with my Prestashop module. I'm trying to send post with order products in hookActionValidateOrder. But if I get an error in API, or it just not working, the customer "confirm order page" is not loading(because it's waiting for API to answer).

The question is: Can I somehow make request send with WORKERS or jobs. Or should make  with ajax code and pass it to the "confirm order page" template, so it would send the request after a user saw a page and it doesn't block with a request. Sorry about my English, I hope you will understand my question

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
      {
        if (Configuration::get('MY_API_STATUS') == 1) {
            $id_order = $params['order']->id;
            $products = $params['order']->getProducts();
            $data = [];
            $data['account_id'] = Configuration::get('MY_API_ACCOUNT_ID');
            $data['project_id'] = Configuration::get('MY_API_PROJECT_ID');
            $data['order_id'] = $id_order;
            $productsData = [];
            foreach ($products as $productItem) {
                $product = array();
                $product['order_id'] = $id_order;
                $product['project_id'] = $data['project_id'];
                $product['account_id'] = $data['account_id'];
                $product['product_id'] = $productItem['product_id'];
                $product['product_cost'] = Product::getPriceStatic($productItem['product_id']);
                $product['quantity'] = $productItem['product_quantity'];
                $productsData[] = $product;
            }
            $data['products'] = $productsData;
            $returned = static::sendData($this->orderHookUrl, $data);
        }
        return;
    }
```

this is the sendData code

```
private function sendData($url, $dataJson)
    {
        $payload = json_encode($dataJson);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . Tools::strlen($payload)));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
```

The question how to do that without blocking a hook, so customer can see a confirm page without waiting for respond from api.

Comment: Please, provide what you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @RMPR , code is here